# Complex Shoelace Theorem

Tags: complex-numbers

I am learning about complex numbers and I have found this theorem similar to the shoelace theorem for Cartesian Coordinates

[image]

But im not sure how to calculate this (?). I can't find any explanation online. I know basic matrices but I have never encountered that a matrix has a value (?)

Comment: The array of terms with vertical bars on the left and right is not a matrix. It’s a determinant. A matrix is written with left and right brackets or parentheses. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: What theorem??!! You just have an algebraic expression (i.e., the determinant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a determinant of a matrix (you can tell by the absolute value signs on the matrix). For information on what a determinant is, as well as how to calculate it, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant